# My own unix performance monitor for a process

Tags: performance, bash, shell

I am trying to write a script that monitors %cpu %mem, cpu time etc (the more the better) of a certain process. Something like performance monitor on Windows (perfmon).
I know that there are some tools already done for that but i have to do it using basic and build in functions because it has to work on both linux and (solaris*/aix/hpux).
It would be great to have output similar to that from perfmon.exe so that i will have output log updated lets say every 5 seconds of tracked process in format:

```
date %mem %cpu cputime private_bytes(?) virtual_bytes(?)
```

I do not know whether to extract data from top ( which in fact  is not the same on all of os's that will be used) or try to extract it from 'ps' query.

I am try to do so by some for loop like:

```
for $count; do   
    sleep $delay  
    date >>output.txt  
    ps -A -o pid,%cpu,%mem,time -o comm= | grep -v grep | grep $process >> output.txt  
done
```

I would appreciate any hints.

BR

Comment: On Linux you'll use `/proc/` so read its documentation.

Comment: `/proc` would be pretty not portable

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
ps -o pid,user,%cpu,%mem,rss,vsize,time,cmd -C NAME
```

or

```
ps -o pid,user,%cpu,%mem,rss,vsize,time,cmd -p PID
```

Don't use `-A` if you're only interested in particular processes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If portability between different Unices is the goal, your approach seems OK (`grep -v` is not needed though) but be careful to use common `ps` switches

Comment: Viz. you can do something like `p=${process#?}; grep "[${process%$p}]$p"`

Comment: Since he wants to monitor a particular process, there's no need for `grep` at all. Use either `-C` or `-p` to make `ps` show the data of a particular command or PID.